# How can I utilize a partial index for the calculated filter condition in a where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have this simple query:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    audiences a
WHERE
    a.created_at >= (current_date - INTERVAL '5 days');
```

This is a 1GB+ table with a partial index on `created_at` column. When I run this query it does sequential scan and does not utilise my index which obviously takes much time:

```
Aggregate  (cost=345853.43..345853.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=27126.426..27126.426 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on audiences a  (cost=0.00..345840.46 rows=5188 width=0) (actual time=97.564..27124.317 rows=8029 loops=1)
        Filter: (created_at >= (('now'::cstring)::date - '5 days'::interval))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2215612
Planning time: 0.131 ms
Execution time: 27126.458 ms
```

On the other hand if I'd have a "hardcoded" (or pre-calculated) value like this:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    audiences a
WHERE
    a.created_at >= TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00';
```

It would utilise an index on created_at:

```
Aggregate  (cost=253.18..253.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1014.655..1014.655 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using index_audiences_on_created_at on audiences a  (cost=0.29..240.21 rows=5188 width=0) (actual time=1.308..1011.071 rows=8029 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (created_at >= '2020-10-16 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
        Heap Fetches: 6185
Planning time: 1.878 ms
Execution time: 1014.716 ms
```

If I could I'd just use an ORM and generate a query with the right value but I can't. Is there a way I can maybe pre-calculate this timestamp and use it in a WHERE clause via plain SQL?

---

Adding a little bit of tech info of my setup.

PostgreSQL version: 9.6.11

created_at column type is: `timestamp`

index: `"index_audiences_on_created_at" btree (created_at) WHERE created_at > '2020-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone`

Comment: What if you fix the types so they match:  `WHERE
    a.created_at >= (current_date - INTERVAL '5 days')::timestamp`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just tried that - the same result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: can you please post your indexes which include created_at

Comment: @itzMEonTV I updated the question with tech info regarding the index (I only have a single index on that column)

Comment: Just create the index on the **bare** column and it will work. (your index looks like yielding a boolean, anyway)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the output of "\d audiences" as in psql

Comment: Ah, a filtered index. Yes the optimizer isn't smart enough to detect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the exact answer. But can do with specific situation

As you have the predicate `(created_at > '2020-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)` , if the filtering condition is greater than the predicate condition. Then you can prepend the condition in `where`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    audiences a
WHERE
    a.created_at >= TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00'
    and
    a.created_at >= (current_date - INTERVAL '5 days');
```

Note: may be instead of `TIMESTAMP` , you have to put `TIMESTAMP without time zone` or `TIMESTAMP with time zone`. Depends on column type

Comment: Still, I'd expect PG to be a bit more smart :) Though it looks like in pg 11 it behaves as expected.

Comment: The optimizer is plenty smart. When you put a where on the index and not on the query you essentially told the optimizer "do not use this index". The optimizer chooses the access path before VALUES (current_date - INTERVAL '5 days') are evaluated. Thus it can not know that the where in the index in is satisfied so it must choose to not use the index.

Comment: But probably the index is used only for the first condition and the second one is realized by a filter. Thus the index acts like a partitioning. If the partial index is large, it will have no significant effect and Postgres will not use it. The answer of @a_horse_with_no_name is certainly the better way.

Answer (score 3):

You have a partial index, and the optimizer is not smart enough to evaluate the expression in the where clause and then choose the partial index based on the expression's result.

So there is not much you can do, except creating an index *without* a WHERE clause.

Comment: Hey, yeah the optimizer is not smart enough as we can see, however it turned out we can force it to pick up the index by prepending an index predicate in a where clause!

Comment: @DannyOcean: does the partial index really improve things that much  on a table with just 2 million rows? Why not simply create an index without a WHERE clause?

Comment: Well I wanted to use it since pg has that _feature_ and it seemed totally legit to me to have a partial index since I added it for a specific query that wouldn't utilize it for dates before specified one. I did not expect that behaviour thus you see my question here. If I'd know I'll need to prepend it like that perhaps I'd just create a regular index.

Comment: For the performance of a regular index: please see my answer. Also: take a look at the partial index present there.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best approach is to create a PL function. I think the problem is that it is evaluating this `(current_date - INTERVAL '5 days')` for every row.

So you would have to create a PL that evaluates it once and then use it for the query. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_audiences(
    vinterval text -- to send interval dynamically
)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
DECLARE
    vdate timestamp;
    vcount integer := 0;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT current_date - INTERVAL '''||vinterval||'''' INTO vdate;-- obtain date
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    INTO
        vcount
    FROM
        audiences a
    WHERE
        a.created_at >= vdate;
    RETURN vcount;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After creating the PL, you just have to call it like:

```
SELECT * FROM count_audiences('5 days');
```

In this way you can also use an ORM to call for the function.

Comment: No need for a function. Overly complex, too. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Works here (given a usable index on `created_at`):

---

```
select version();

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    tweets a
WHERE
    a.created_at >= (current_date - INTERVAL '5 days')
    ;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    tweets a
WHERE
    a.created_at >= TIMESTAMP '2020-10-16 00:00:00'
        ;

\d tweets
```

---

Output:

---

```
                                                version                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit
(1 row)

                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2.90..2.91 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.100..0.101 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using tweets_du_idx on tweets a  (cost=0.56..2.90 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.088..0.088 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (created_at >= (CURRENT_DATE - '5 days'::interval))
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 2.357 ms
 Execution Time: 0.217 ms
(6 rows)

                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2.89..2.90 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using tweets_du_idx on tweets a  (cost=0.56..2.89 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (created_at >= '2020-10-16 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.163 ms
 Execution Time: 0.045 ms
(6 rows)

                           Table "public.tweets"
     Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 seq            | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 id             | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 user_id        | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 in_reply_to_id | bigint                   |           | not null | 0
 parent_seq     | bigint                   |           | not null | 0
 sucker_id      | integer                  |           | not null | 0
 created_at     | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 [snip
 body           | text                     |           |          | 
 zoek           | tsvector                 |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "tweets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (seq)
    "tweets_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
    "tweets_stamp_idx" UNIQUE, btree (fetch_stamp, seq)
    "tweets_userid_id" UNIQUE, btree (user_id, id)
    "tweets_du_idx" btree (created_at, user_id)
    "tweets_id_idx" btree (id) WHERE need_refetch = true
    "tweets_in_reply_to_id_created_at_idx" btree (in_reply_to_id, created_at) WHERE is_retweet = false AND did_resolve = false AND in_reply_to_id > 0
    "tweets_in_reply_to_id_fp" btree (in_reply_to_id)
    "tweets_parent_seq_fk" btree (parent_seq)
    "tweets_ud_idx" btree (user_id, created_at)
    "tweets_zoek" gin (zoek)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "tweets_parent_seq_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_seq) REFERENCES tweets(seq)
    "tweets_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES tweeps(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tweets" CONSTRAINT "tweets_parent_seq_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_seq) REFERENCES tweets(seq)
Triggers:
    tr_upd_zzoek_i BEFORE INSERT ON tweets FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf_tweets_upd_zzoek()
    tr_upd_zzoek_u BEFORE UPDATE ON tweets FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.body <> old.body) EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf_tweets_upd_zzoek()
```

Comment: Is your index partial?  This is a problem specifically with partial indexes.

Comment: No. it is a composite index on {created_at, user_id}. (the OP wasn't very clear about his index)